# How do I get the time intervals between transaction data?

Tags: r

I have a tibble which has different itemIDs. 
What I want is the difference between timestamps, based on the itemID.

```
  time                itemID order salesPrice time_year time_week time_day   time_diff
  <dttm>               <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <date>         <dbl>
1 2018-02-24 19:35:26      2     1       9.15      2018         8 2018-02-24       113
2 2018-02-26 21:39:53      2     1       9.15      2018         9 2018-02-26       101
3 2018-05-27 16:33:25      2     1       9.15      2018        21 2018-05-27       208
4 2018-05-29 22:10:40      2     2       9.15      2018        22 2018-05-29        25
```

So the `time_diff` should **not be like above**, it should be like follow (time_diff in seconds):

```
  time                itemID order salesPrice time_year time_week time_day   time_diff
  <dttm>               <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <date>         <dbl>
1 2018-02-24 19:35:26      2     1       9.15      2018         8 2018-02-24       0
2 2018-02-26 21:39:53      2     1       9.15      2018         9 2018-02-26       180267
3 2018-05-27 16:33:25      2     1       9.15      2018        21 2018-05-27       7754012 
4 2018-05-29 22:10:40      2     2       9.15      2018        22 2018-05-29       193035
```

e.g.

```
"2018-05-29 22:10:40" (last transaction) - "2018-05-27 16:33:25" (actual transaction) = 193035 seconds
```

---

Reproduction:

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1514764916, 1514764916, 1514765231, 
1514765364, 1514765364, 1514767166, 1514767919, 1514767919, 1514767919, 
1514767919, 1514767919, 1514767919, 1514768104, 1514768214, 1514768214, 
1514768214, 1514768214, 1514768214, 1514768214, 1514770106, 1514770983, 
1514770983, 1514782167, 1514784574, 1514787174, 1514788305, 1514791067, 
1514791068, 1514791069, 1514791070, 1514793524, 1514793525, 1514795443, 
1514795443, 1514795444, 1514795445, 1514795446, 1514796571, 1514798636, 
1514798637, 1514798638, 1514798639, 1514798640, 1514798641, 1514799127, 
1514799230, 1514799230, 1514799230, 1514799231, 1514799837, 1514800396, 
1514800396, 1514800705, 1514800742, 1514800812, 1514801630, 1514801631, 
1514801632, 1514801633, 1514801634, 1514801635, 1514801636, 1514801637, 
1514801638, 1514801639, 1514801639, 1514801640, 1514801641, 1514801642, 
1514801643, 1514801643, 1514801644, 1514801645, 1514801646, 1514801647, 
1514801648, 1514801649, 1514801649, 1514801650, 1514801651, 1514801652, 
1514801653, 1514801654, 1514801654, 1514801655, 1514801656, 1514801657, 
1514801658, 1514801659, 1514801660, 1514801661, 1514801662, 1514801663, 
1514801664, 1514801665, 1514801666, 1514801667, 1514801668, 1514801669, 
1514801670), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    itemID = c(83, 450, 7851, 83, 450, 9375, 19, 83, 109, 295, 
    297, 450, 2049, 19, 83, 109, 295, 297, 450, 4322, 7975, 8192, 
    5007, 2013, 6744, 386, 529, 529, 529, 529, 222, 222, 5094, 
    6653, 5094, 5094, 5094, 138, 561, 561, 561, 561, 561, 561, 
    5022, 222, 6574, 6575, 9368, 222, 8075, 8107, 520, 520, 520, 
    35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 520, 520, 520, 520, 
    222, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 222, 520, 520, 520, 520, 
    520, 113, 520, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 
    113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113), order = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
    4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 
    2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3, 6, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    3), salesPrice = c(5.19, 17.42, 20.47, 5.19, 17.42, 31.02, 
    77.64, 5.19, 5.8, 37.79, 43.53, 17.42, 35.75, 77.64, 5.19, 
    5.8, 37.79, 43.53, 17.42, 22.86, 2.84, 29.92, 23.11, 17.11, 
    24.66, 45.53, 69.56, 69.56, 69.56, 69.56, 4.7, 4.7, 112.26, 
    3.11, 112.26, 112.26, 112.26, 11.85, 116.16, 116.16, 116.16, 
    116.16, 116.16, 116.16, 13.46, 4.7, 12.69, 17.93, 420.67, 
    4.7, 2.02, 25.24, 9.32, 9.32, 9.32, 368.13, 368.13, 368.13, 
    368.13, 368.13, 368.13, 368.13, 368.13, 368.13, 368.13, 9.32, 
    9.32, 9.32, 9.32, 4.7, 9.32, 9.32, 9.32, 9.32, 9.32, 9.32, 
    4.7, 9.32, 9.32, 9.32, 9.32, 9.32, 3.42, 9.32, 3.42, 3.42, 
    3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 
    3.42, 3.42, 3.42, 3.42), time_year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), time_week = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), time_day = structure(c(17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
    17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532), class = "Date"), 
    time_diff = c(NA, 0, 315, 133, 0, 1802, 753, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 185, 110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1892, 877, 0, 11184, 2407, 2600, 
    1131, 2762, 1, 1, 1, 2454, 1, 1918, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1125, 2065, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 486, 103, 0, 0, 1, 606, 559, 0, 309, 37, 70, 
    818, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), groups = structure(list(
    itemID = c(19, 19, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
    83, 83, 83, 83, 109, 109, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 
    113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 138, 222, 
    222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 295, 295, 297, 297, 386, 450, 450, 
    450, 450, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 
    520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520, 529, 529, 529, 
    529, 561, 561, 561, 561, 561, 561, 2013, 2049, 4322, 5007, 
    5022, 5094, 5094, 5094, 5094, 6574, 6575, 6653, 6744, 7851, 
    7975, 8075, 8107, 8192, 9368, 9375), time = structure(c(1514767919, 
    1514768214, 1514801630, 1514801631, 1514801632, 1514801633, 
    1514801634, 1514801635, 1514801636, 1514801637, 1514801638, 
    1514801639, 1514764916, 1514765364, 1514767919, 1514768214, 
    1514767919, 1514768214, 1514801654, 1514801655, 1514801656, 
    1514801657, 1514801658, 1514801659, 1514801660, 1514801661, 
    1514801662, 1514801663, 1514801664, 1514801665, 1514801666, 
    1514801667, 1514801668, 1514801669, 1514801670, 1514796571, 
    1514793524, 1514793525, 1514799230, 1514799837, 1514801643, 
    1514801649, 1514767919, 1514768214, 1514767919, 1514768214, 
    1514788305, 1514764916, 1514765364, 1514767919, 1514768214, 
    1514800705, 1514800742, 1514800812, 1514801639, 1514801640, 
    1514801641, 1514801642, 1514801643, 1514801644, 1514801645, 
    1514801646, 1514801647, 1514801648, 1514801649, 1514801650, 
    1514801651, 1514801652, 1514801653, 1514801654, 1514791067, 
    1514791068, 1514791069, 1514791070, 1514798636, 1514798637, 
    1514798638, 1514798639, 1514798640, 1514798641, 1514784574, 
    1514768104, 1514770106, 1514782167, 1514799127, 1514795443, 
    1514795444, 1514795445, 1514795446, 1514799230, 1514799230, 
    1514795443, 1514787174, 1514765231, 1514770983, 1514800396, 
    1514800396, 1514770983, 1514799231, 1514767166), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .rows = structure(list(7L, 14L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
        59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 15L, 9L, 
        16L, 83L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
        94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 38L, 31L, 32L, 46L, 
        50L, 70L, 77L, 10L, 17L, 11L, 18L, 26L, 2L, 5L, 12L, 
        19L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 
        74L, 75L, 76L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 27L, 28L, 
        29L, 30L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 24L, 13L, 20L, 
        23L, 45L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 47L, 48L, 34L, 25L, 3L, 
        21L, 51L, 52L, 22L, 49L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -100L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution using `difftime`:

```
> difftime(as.POSIXct("2018-05-29 22:10:40"), as.POSIXct("2018-05-27 16:33:25"), units = "secs")
Time difference of 193035 secs
```

**Solution with dplyr**. First you order by itemID, then group, and finally get the time lagged with function `lag`. Finally use `difftime` setting units to secs:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% arrange(desc(itemID)) %>% group_by(itemID) %>%
mutate(lag.time = dplyr::lag(time, n = 1, default = as.POSIXct(NA)))

df <- transform(df,time_diff = difftime(as.POSIXct(time), 
as.POSIXct(lag.time), units = "secs"))
```

Another posible solution with `shift` function from `data.table`, that also keep the datetime format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df <- df %>% arrange(desc(itemID)) %>% data.table::data.table()
df <- df %>% group_by(itemID) %>%
 mutate(lag.time = data.table::shift(time))

df <- transform(df,time_diff = difftime(as.POSIXct(time), 
as.POSIXct(lag.time), units = "secs"))
```

Output:

```
                   time itemID order salesPrice time_year time_week   time_day time_diff            lag.time
83  2018-01-01 00:51:59    109     1       5.80      2018         1 2018-01-01   NA secs                <NA>
84  2018-01-01 00:56:54    109     1       5.80      2018         1 2018-01-01  295 secs 2018-01-01 00:51:59
85  2018-01-01 00:01:56     83     1       5.19      2018         1 2018-01-01   NA secs                <NA>
86  2018-01-01 00:09:24     83     1       5.19      2018         1 2018-01-01  448 secs 2018-01-01 00:01:56
87  2018-01-01 00:51:59     83     1       5.19      2018         1 2018-01-01 2555 secs 2018-01-01 00:09:24
88  2018-01-01 00:56:54     83     1       5.19      2018         1 2018-01-01  295 secs 2018-01-01 00:51:59
89  2018-01-01 10:13:50     35     2     368.13      2018         1 2018-01-01   NA secs                <NA>
90  2018-01-01 10:13:51     35     3     368.13      2018         1 2018-01-01    1 secs 2018-01-01 10:13:50
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner using `ave`.

```
df$time_diff <- with(df, ave(as.numeric(time), itemID, FUN=\(x) -c(0, x[-length(x)] - x[-1])))


## check 
df[df$itemID == 450, ]
#                   time itemID order salesPrice time_year time_week   time_day time_diff
# 2  2018-01-01 00:01:56    450     1      17.42      2018         1 2018-01-01         0
# 5  2018-01-01 00:09:24    450     1      17.42      2018         1 2018-01-01       448
# 12 2018-01-01 00:51:59    450     1      17.42      2018         1 2018-01-01      2555
# 19 2018-01-01 00:56:54    450     1      17.42      2018         1 2018-01-01       295
```